# How to use dplyr to group_by() to colllapse subseries

Tags: r, dplyr

thank you for helping! I am not an R expert, but have had some experience using it and I have a difficult question that I am trying to figure out. In this instance, I am running a simulation to create a sub-sereies of events:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 3
   GeneID  counts       Freq
   <fct>    <int>      <dbl>
 1 1.1          3 0.0000132 
 2 1.2          4 0.0000176 
 3 1.3          5 0.0000220 
 4 1.4          2 0.00000880
 5 10.1         1 0.00000440
 6 10.2         4 0.0000176 
 7 10.3         1 0.00000440
 8 10.4         2 0.00000880
 9 10.5         3 0.0000132 
10 100.1        5 0.0000220 
11 100.2        5 0.0000220 
12 100.3        2 0.00000880
13 100.4        2 0.00000880
14 100.5        2 0.00000880
```

where in GeneID, I have 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 and 1.4 which are variations of Gene 1 (and the same principle for the others). Is it possible to use group_by from dplyr to collapse the variations into a single group? ie. 1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4 to group into 1 and sum the associated counts (and so on for all the rest)?

I've thought about creating another column using trunc() to remove the decimals, but these data sets can be quite large....

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on right track, you can create a new column by removing everything after `"."` in `GeneID` and take `sum` for each unique value.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Gene_group = sub('\\..*', '', GeneID)) %>%
  summarise(Freq = sum(Freq))

# Gene_group      Freq
#  <chr>          <dbl>
#1 1          0.0000616
#2 10         0.0000484
#3 100        0.0000704
```

If your dataset is huge and you are worried about performance you can use the above in `data.table` as well.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Gene_group := sub('\\..*', '', GeneID)]
df[, sum(Freq), Gene_group]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(GeneID = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 
10.4, 10.5, 100.1, 100.2, 100.3, 100.4, 100.5), counts = c(3L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Freq = c(1.32e-05, 
1.76e-05, 2.2e-05, 8.8e-06, 4.4e-06, 1.76e-05, 4.4e-06, 8.8e-06, 
1.32e-05, 2.2e-05, 2.2e-05, 8.8e-06, 8.8e-06, 8.8e-06)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```

Comment: Great, looks like it's working...will try my large data set soon. I did not realize that you could pass through a string operation within the group_by operation!

Answer (score 0):

Will this work:

```
> df$GeneGroup <- gsub('(.*)\\.([0-9]+)','\\1',df$GeneID)
> df
# A tibble: 14 x 4
   GeneID counts      Freq GeneGroup
    <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>    
 1    1.1      3 0.0000132 1        
 2    1.2      4 0.0000176 1        
 3    1.3      5 0.000022  1        
 4    1.4      2 0.0000088 1        
 5   10.1      1 0.0000044 10       
 6   10.2      4 0.0000176 10       
 7   10.3      1 0.0000044 10       
 8   10.4      2 0.0000088 10       
 9   10.5      3 0.0000132 10       
10  100.       5 0.000022  100      
11  100.       5 0.000022  100      
12  100.       2 0.0000088 100      
13  100.       2 0.0000088 100      
14  100.       2 0.0000088 100      
> df %>% group_by(GeneGroup) %>% summarise(Total_Count = sum(counts))
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  GeneGroup Total_Count
  <chr>           <dbl>
1 1                  14
2 10                 11
3 100                16
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(Freq ~ cbind(Gene_group = as.integer(GeneID)), df, sum)
#  Gene_group     Freq
#1          1 6.16e-05
#2         10 4.84e-05
#3        100 7.04e-05
```

Comment: Ah, thank you....forgot about the aggregate function...I will give it a try as well. Thanks!